# MySQL Gem, Ubuntu & UTF8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems

I have a web-app that was done in Rails 1.2.3 and I have just migrated it to rails 2.2.2 and upon deploy the app broke. It turns out I needed to install the MySQL gem since rails 2.2.2 needs this.

So, I did install it but I had to install with "sudo gem install mysql -- -with-mysql-config" (as per http://brantinteractive.com/2007/02/16/getting-the-mysql-gem-installed-on-ubuntu/) and that seemed to do the trick. I am on Ubuntu 6.06.2 LTS Dapper.

The app wouldn't boot up in production still. So I booted with script/console production and this is what came back:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 2.2.2)
Character set 'utf8' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index' file
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:548:in `real_connect':Mysql::Error: Can't initialize character set utf8 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)
>>
```

I did some searching around on this error and somebody said that the mysql client I am using (the MySQL gem!) isn't connecting using UTF8. I don't know how to install this gem any other way so that it installs correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: actually there's a mysql-client library installed. Please check what version that is. Also what version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Well, on that tutorial link I posted above, I ran "apt-get install libmysqlclient12-dev" before installing the gem. I had to do that before the gem would install.

MySQL version is 5.0.22.

Comment: Do you have a locale explicitly set in your database.yml?

Comment: Yes I have encoding set to UTF8 in database.yml.

Comment: OK, I installed libmysqlclient15-dev which removed the libmysqlclient12-dev that I had installed. I uninstalled the gem and re-installed it using "sudo gem install mysql -- -with-mysql-config" - and now I can boot up the script/console without it giving an error. I cloned my production slice so I can experiment without too much consequence. It worked so far! So the test will be to deploy back to production my rails 2.2.2 upgrade. 

Will report back if that worked. I don't know too much about what libmysqlclient12-dev vs libmysqlclient15-dev is other than it must be a newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed. Installing libmysqlclient15-dev overtop of  libmysqlclient12-dev did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the compatible version with MySql version installed, like mysql-2.7.3.gem, would go well with mysql 5.1 or higher, but would have problems with 5.0.
secondly check if your mysql is installed properly like to mysql prompt try creating database.
then if both of the issues are resolved, just verify the socket path of your mysql installation and add that to your database.yml file.

```
socket /var/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these 2 steps to install mysql gem 2.7

sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

sudo gem install mysql –v 2.7